# Ways to display data in SwiftUI - Alternatives to List

Tags: swift, xcode, listview, swiftui

[image]I'm display how many steps I have taken but don't want it in a list. What should I use instead? Thanks

```
NavigationView {
        
    
        List(steps, id: \.id) { step in
            
            VStack(spacing: 15){
                Text("\(step.count)")
                    .font(.custom(customFont, size: 100))
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .opacity(5)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .padding(.bottom, -45)

                HStack{
                    
                    Text("Steps Today")
                        .font(.custom(customFont, size: 40))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
                
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
               
        }
```

Comment: Try `ScrollView { LazyVStack { ForEach(steps, id: \.id) { step in /* ... */ } } }`

Comment: @aheze thank you! That's very helpful

Comment: @aheze I've put a NavigationView around the Scrollview and inside the ScrollView, I have a customNavigationLink. Once I return to the original page after tapping the link everything is duplicated. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by duplicated? Please share the code.

Comment: @ChrisR I'm new to stack overflow and when I try to edit the question it says I have too much code in it and won't let me post

Comment: @Mxyb try making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - only include the code necessary to reproduce the problem, but nothing more. Makes it easier to debug since we can just copy and paste your code into our computer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

following @aheze and generally speaking it should look something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(steps, id: \.id) { step in
                        
                        NavigationLink {
                            // here comes the destination view, this is only dummy
                            Text("I walked \(step.count) steps")
                        } label: {
                            Text("\(step.count)")
                                .font(.system(size: 100))
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the what I am trying to do however I am still experiencing the same issue. After I have tapped on the NavigationLink then click "back" the number of steps is displayed twice

Comment: well, i would need to see your data struct and also the detail view

Comment: Yeah, I think I have an issue in the data struct I believe I see the reason hopefully it works! Thanks of your help